# Compare two files using batch

Tags: batch-file

I have two files file1.txt and file2.txt

```
File1.txt:

abc
def
xyz

File2.txt

abc
```

Compare both file1.txt and file2.txt and create two files one with differences and the other showing the similarities.
Can anyone help me with such a batch program.

Comment: `Can anyone help me with such a batch program` -- You mean write one for you?

Comment: `fc /?`, `find /?`and `findstr /?` may be a good starting point.

Answer (score 2):

Windows code for GNU [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk "NR==FNR {a[$0]=$0; next}; {b[$0]=$0};a[$0]==$0;END {for (i in a) {if (b[i]==0) {print a[i] >\"diff.txt\"}};for (i in b) {if (a[i]==0) {print b[i]>>\"diff.txt\"}}}" file1 file2
```

---

Output example:

```
>type file1,file2

file1


AAAAA
44444
BBBBB
55555
CCCCC
66666
DDDDD

file2


AAAAA
11111
BBBBB
22222
CCCCC
33333
DDDDD

>awk "NR==FNR {a[$0]=$0; next}; {b[$0]=$0};a[$0]==$0;END {for (i in a) {if (b[i]==0) {print a[i] >\"diff.txt\"}};for (i in b) {if (a[i]==0) {print b[i]>>\"diff.txt\"}}}" file1 file2>match.txt

>type match.txt,diff.txt

match.txt


AAAAA
BBBBB
CCCCC
DDDDD

diff.txt


44444
55555
66666
11111
22222
33333

>
```

---

In pure [batch](/questions/tagged/batch):

```
findstr /l /g:file1 file2>match.txt
findstr /lv /g:file1 file2>diff.txt
findstr /lv /g:file2 file1>>diff.txt
```